# Why server controls are underlined when placed inside Content tags?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have a Web Content Form containing a `Div` and various Server controls like `DropDownList`. When I run the application, it runs well without any errors, but when I view the HTML source, the Server controls are red underlined. On bringing the mouse over, say, `DropDownList`, a tooltip warning is displayed:

```
DropDownList is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in a website.
```

**Edited**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="contentReportSchemesMenu.aspx.cs" Inherits="contentReportMenu" Title="Reports Menu" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentReportMenu" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div id="divMenu" class="divMenu" runat="server">
        <table id="tblMenuLayout" class="Options" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="Top">Scheme Reports Menu</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Left">Report Type</td>
                <td class="Right">
                        &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReportType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReportType_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>        
            <tr>
                <td class="Left">Select District</td>
                <td class="Right">
                        &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistrict" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged" Enabled="False"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Left">Select Block</td>
                <td class="Right">
                    &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBlock" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBlock_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Enabled="False" />
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This doesn't happen udner similar conditions on my site. Could you post some of your html?

Comment: @Oliver Code added. See original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google search soon found the solution: Delete the files from “C:\Documents and Settings[Username]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas” folder (or “…\VisualStudio\8.0\…” if running Visual Studio 2005) in Windows XP. In Windows 7 it is under "C:\Users{User Profile}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft...etc". Remember also the "VisualStudio" part of the path will be different depending on the version installed.

I closed Visual Studio (always a good ideas for changes that will affect the IDE), deleted the files then re-opened the project. The warnings were gone.

I found references to this solution at:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1205528.aspx 
http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2005/04/21/410557.aspx

FYI, the search term I used in Google was “element is not supported”.

I don't know why this happens but I do know there are some flakey domain profile things happening in the network environmnet.

Answer (score 3):

You're receiving this error because the `table` is running at the server, but the `tr` and `td` elements are not. When you specify `runat="server"` on a table element, it expects child elements to run at the server as well.

There are two easy ways to verify this:

1. Remove `runat="server"` from the table declaration;
2. Take the DropDownList(s) outside of the table

Try one of these two options, and see if it fixes the problem.

**EDIT**

Make sure that the *ContentPlaceHolderID* on the content form matches the ID of the corresponding content area in the master page. If that doesn't fix your problem, try creating a new content form, applying the advice above, and add a control to the form in the content area. If there are no errors, then you know the issue is somewhere in your markup.

Comment: I followed your first suggestion, the problem persists. It is not possible to bring DropDowns outside of the table. I have not tried out table-less design.

Comment: Sometimes it takes a minute to propagate to the editor. Did you try closing and reopening the page, and waiting a minute for the changes to reach the editor?

Comment: I removed runat-"server" from the Table and Tr, Td as well, but still the same underlines.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the schema cache. To do this, close Visual Studio and delete all of the files in the following directory:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas

Once the files have been deleted, open Visual Studio again and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: I am using VS-2005 on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Try the following path: `C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ReflectedSchemas`.

Comment: Did exactly what you said but the underlines still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You said that `"when I view the HTML source, the Server controls are red underlined"`, but HTML source can not contains such elements like `DropDownList` because this is the ASP.NET control which is generated as HTML [Select tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). Considering that common solution with schema cleanup is not helped you perhaps a problem is in an other place...  I'll try to assume that you are opening ASPX/ASCX file itself using some third party editor which is not aware of ASP.NET controls, am I right?

Comment: No, I am opening it in VS-2005.