# Not able to pass ASP server control value to javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using ASP.NET 2.0.

I have various ASP.NET Server Controls like TextBoxes on my Entry Form. I want to pass TextBox value on **onBlur** event. A sample TextBox code is as below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalTw" Width="80px" runat="server" MaxLength="10" onBlur="isNumber(this.Value);"></asp:TextBox>
```

In the code-behind I added below line:

```
txtTotalTw.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "javascript:isNumber(this.Value)");
```

The JavaScript is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function isNumber(n) {
  alert(n);
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
</script>
```

I added `alert(n)` to check whether value is passed or not. The value is not passing from the `onBlur` event. The alert message displays 'undefined'.

How to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove onBlur from your aspx template file. Just leave one you have added from code-behind. and it will work.

Comment: Thanks. A little help more needed is that I want to set the focus to the TextBox where a non-numeric entry detected.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove onBlur:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalTw" Width="80px" runat="server" MaxLength="10" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**javascript prefix is not needed:**

```
txtTotalTw.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "isNumber(this.value);");
```

Answer (score 1):

As Senad said, remove the extra call in the markup and change,

this.Value to this.value.

JavaScript is case sensitive and Value is not defined, but value is.

---

To set focus back to the control
Change the code behind to

```
txtTotalTw.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "javascript:isNumber(this)")
```

and change the function to something like this

```
function isNumber(ctrl) {
  var t = ctrl.value;
  var n = parseFloat(t);       
  if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n)) {
    ctrl.focus();
  }
```

Comment: This works great but unfortunately it is not guaranteed to work because of another VS-2005 issue. See my another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752496/why-server-controls-are-underlined-when-placed-inside-content-tags

Comment: Not sure how this relates . . . you mention that the site runs, but you have a problem in the IDE